# Subsetting a dataframe based on cell color and text color in excel sheet

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, styleframe

I have an excel sheet with more than 1000 columns and 300 rows. Some these cells have normal data, while some cells have a background color of red and some cells have normal white background but the text is red in color. For example, my excel sheet looks like below:

[image]

I am reading this excel sheet into Python (pandas) to use it as a dataframe and perform further actions on it. However, the red text and red cells need to be treated differently than the normal cells.

Therefore, I would like to split the above table into 3 tables, such that: Table one has all the cells but the red background cells are empty. Table 2 has only those rows and columns where the text is red. Table 3 has only those rows and columns where the background is red.

I guess it cannot be done in Pandas. I tried using StyleFrame but failed.

Can anyone help in this regard? Is there any python package that is helpful in this case?

Comment: You can use `StyleFrame.read_excel` with argument `use_openpyxl_styles=False` to be able to use pandas style indexing based on cells' style, as suggested in the docs: https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_documentation.html#read-excel

Comment: I did that. Now I have the complete dataframe read into a variable. Now the question is how do i filter out the cells based on their formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much the way to achieve this. It is **not pretty** as StyleFrame wasn't really designed to be used this way.

Reading the source Excel file

```
import numpy as np
from styleframe import StyleFrame, utils

sf = StyleFrame.read_excel('test.xlsx', read_style=True, use_openpyxl_styles=False)
```

## 1) All cells but cells with red background are empty

```
def empty_red_background_cells(cell):
    if cell.style.bg_color in {utils.colors.red, 'FFFF0000'}:
        cell.value = np.nan
    return cell

sf_1 = StyleFrame(sf.applymap(empty_red_background_cells))    
print(sf_1)
#      C1       C2 C3    C4      C5      C6
# 0    a1      1.0  s   nan  1001.0  1234.0
# 1    a2     12.0  s   nan  1001.0  4322.0
# 2    a3      nan  s   nan  1001.0  4432.0
# 3    a4    232.0  s   nan  1001.0  4432.0
# 4    a5    343.0  s  99.0     nan     nan
# 5    a6      3.0  s  99.0  1001.0  4432.0
# 6    a7     34.0  s  99.0  1001.0  4432.0
# 7    a8      5.0  s   nan  1001.0  4432.0
# 8    a9      6.0  s  99.0  1001.0  4432.0
# 9   a10    565.0  s  99.0     nan  4432.0
# 10  a11   5543.0  s  99.0  1001.0  4432.0
# 11  a12    112.0  s  99.0  1001.0     nan
# 12  a13  34345.0  s  99.0  1001.0  4432.0
# 13  a14      0.0  s  99.0     nan     nan
# 14  a15    453.0  s  99.0  1001.0     nan
```

## 2) Only cells with red text

```
def only_cells_with_red_text(cell):
    return cell if cell.style.font_color in {utils.colors.red, 'FFFF0000'} else np.nan
      
sf_2 = StyleFrame(sf.applymap(only_cells_with_red_text).dropna(axis=(0, 1), how='all'))
# passing a tuple to pandas.dropna is deprecated since pandas 0.23.0, but this can be
# avoided by simply calling dropna twice, once with axis=0 and once with axis=1

print(sf_2)
#         C2      C6
# 7     nan   4432.0
# 8     nan   4432.0
# 9    565.0     nan
# 10  5543.0     nan
# 11   112.0     nan
```

## 3) Only cells with red background

```
def only_cells_with_red_background(cell):
    return cell if cell.style.bg_color in {utils.colors.red, 'FFFF0000'} else np.nan

sf_3 = StyleFrame(sf.applymap(only_cells_with_red_background).dropna(axis=(0, 1), how='all'))
# passing a tuple to pandas.dropna is deprecated since pandas 0.23.0, but this can be
# avoided by simply calling dropna twice, once with axis=0 and once with axis=1

print(sf_3)
#        C4      C6
# 0    99.0     nan
# 1    99.0     nan
# 2    99.0     nan
# 3    99.0     nan
# 13    nan  4432.0
# 14    nan  4432.0
```

Comment: There was one error though, in sf_3, as there I get an empty dataframe with the columns names as you have specified. I managed to solve this issue by first extracting sf_2 and sf_3 and in the last sf_1. Don't know why it happens as we are using different dataframe names to copy the data to.

Comment: You made some changes to the code due to which it does not work anymore properly. The issue occurs in (1). The code/function empties the next row and not the one that has red text. I am confirming it after running the code on a number of file with 1000x2000 columns/rows and performing the QC. Can you suggest any trick here?

Comment: @Hanif (1) empties cells with red background, not red text

Comment: Sorry I mean to say red background. I tried editing the function to see if it works on red text cells by replacing cell.style.bg_color with cell.style.font_color and get the same problem. The function somehow selects the next immediate row after the row that has either red background or red text. I tried an earlier version of your function in this post and it worked perfectly on a smaller table but I lost that code due some technical reason. Is it possible to state your initial code function somewhere here, maybe that helps? or if you have any better suggestion?

Comment: @Hanif You can see the edit history of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52164554/revisions), but I never edited (1), and I don't see why it would empty the row after, especially after you verified it was working as expected on a smaller table / different file. I suspect the difference is in the files and not the code. If you still face the same issue I think it would be better for us to continue this discussion on Github as a [Github issue](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame/issues/new)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. I will check the code once again tomorrow and if the issue persists then will continue the discussion on Git.

Comment: @DeepSpace I am trying to delete the values of a column having a red background. And I am getting an error saying `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'dropna'` can you please help me with where am I wrong.

Comment: @TwinkleLahariya please ask a new question with the exact code you are using and the error you recieve