# Combine same text color excel cells into one using python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd, styleframe

I'm looking for a solution to combine same text color excel cells into a single cell in a column. The following image shows the input_excel.xlsx :-

[Input image to python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOnoM.png)

The output_excel.xlsx should be returned by python code as follows:-

[Output of python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFfkN.png)

I looked into the following link: [Subsetting a dataframe based on cell color and text color in excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162444/subsetting-a-dataframe-based-on-cell-color-and-text-color-in-excel-sheet) but not able to combine the cells that are having black text color.

The following code was implemented to detect red text and black text in an excel:-

```
# importing openpyxl module 
import openpyxl 

# Give the location of the file 
path = "E:\\input_excel.xlsx"

# workbook object is created 
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active 
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row 
for i in range(1, m_row + 1): 
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1).font.color
    if cell_obj is not None:    # to catch cells that do have a color object
        if cell_obj.rgb == "FFFF0000":
           print(cell_obj.rgb)
        elif cell_obj.rgb == "00000000":
           print(cell_obj.rgb)
```

The above code always returns the red text hex value as follows:-

```
FFFF0000
FFFF0000
FFFF0000
FFFF0000
FFFF0000
```

Why does openpyxl not detect black color text? How can the code be improved? Can anybody help in implementing the code needed for above shown images?

Comment: what happens if you place `print(cell_obj.rgb)` before `if cell_obj.rgb == "FFFF0000":` This should help debug what is actually  assigned to `cell_obj.rgb` prior to matching it. Not sure why however you are using `if cell_obj is not None:` in this instance.

Comment: I believe black is the default color, so cells you call black are in fact cells without color attribute set; and your condition `cell_obj is not None` explicitly filters them out.

Comment: `print(cell_obj.rgb)` before `if cell_obj.rgb == "FFFF0000":` results into - **Values must be of type <class 'str'>** @GerhardBarnard

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Any further suggestions?

Comment: You could set the class to str prior to the print anyway just do another `elif` for when cell_obj is none. Those should then be the black ones you want. You could also set the class to `str` before the loop.